Getting "Comments on locked questions not eligible for voting" when deleting comment
If I click delete and then OK on a comment I made on a now deleted question, I get a strange message not related to the action I try to perform.
The usecase is this: I suggested a poster to visit help pages because the question was very poor. Then I realised it was a spam, and wanted to delete my comment, but in the meantime the question had been closed as spam. I still want to delete my comment but am not allowed. I found the description of the rejection of the delete to be weird and I have been able to delete my comments on other deleted posts.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79280840
I had no problems deleting my comments on this question closed by @Dharman
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79281381/testing-we-can-delete-comments-in-a-question-that-has-been-deleted-in-a-normal-w?noredirect=1#comment139803959_79281381


The post is locked, and you are trying to vote to delete the comment, which you aren't allowed to do. Why do you think the message is unrelated?

I am not voting. It is my comment I made myself. I should not need to "vote"

I see - the post is locked in this case, so interacting with it or the comments is supposed to be restricted.

@VLAZ, note locked, not deleted. Either way, even if we are supposed to be allowed to delete comments on locked posts, if the action is stopped (which it evidently is), then a message saying that would be a stretch to be called "unrelated".

See last part of Shog's answer: "you also can't vote for comments on deleted posts". And deletion is considered as a vote behind the scenes. (delete vote, OP just happens to have a binding vote on comments hence the result is instant deletion.)

Until quite recently I was able to delete my comments, just a couple that I thought were superfluous,  on deleted posts by different authors. I believed the notice that popped up was an error that would be eventually fixed by the developers. I see it has not been fixed. Therefore this question is not a duplicate of your 11-year-old post.

@ShadowWizard please see screenshots https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/404966/223820

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні the post in the question is locked, though, and you can't interact with anything on a locked post. There is probably a better duplicate for that, I guess but the current one still explains that deletion is implemented as a type of vote in the system. I'm not sure about your case - if the post is not locked, then it might be a different problem than the one described here.

Well the screenshots were indeed from a locked question, I had even flagged it as spam. But how would I go about finding a deleted question where I posted a comment, if the comments no longer appear on my activity page? Maybe the other posts where I tried deleting a comment were also locked?

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні this is still duplicate because both are about locked posts, not just deleted. If you, or the OP, can prove you can't delete comments you made on deleted but not locked posts, then I'll reopen.

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні here is a test question if you are quick enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79281381/testing-we-can-delete-comments-in-a-question-that-has-been-deleted-in-a-normal-w

@ShadowWizard No problem deleting my comment in a closed question at all

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні I was able to find one easily simply by browsing my own list of deleted questions.

@mplungjan still not locked. The part that prevents deletion is the post being locked, not only deleted.

I just tested on one of my own old deleted questions, and I was indeed able to delete my own comment on it. (cc @ShadowWizard)

@ShadowWizard I understand. Still not a great error message or UX.

Also, fun fact: until an explicit exemption was implemented for delete votes on comments, comment deletions used to be subject to the same throttle as comment upvotes, because it was implemented for all types of comment votes.
